# URL.openStream() no response

Tags: url, stream, inputstream

I test a this moment. It's to take a picture on ip camera.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    URL url = new URL("http://192.168.1.210:5500/snapshot.cgi?user=admin&pwd=123456");
    InputStream is = url.openStream();
    BufferedImage image = null;
    image = ImageIO.read(is);
    is.close();

}
```

My problem is this line: "InputStream is = url.openStream();" i know that my address is wrong but it stay block and i don't have error or something else. Someone have an idea to fix my problem ? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The Java API doc for [URL.openStream()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#openStream%28%29) says

> Opens a connection to this URL and returns an InputStream for reading from that connection. This method is a shorthand for:
>
> openConnection().getInputStream()

So, you could try to first open a connection via `openConnection()`, then set at timeout at that object, and then call `getInputStream()`, maybe that will work.

```
    URLConnection urlcon = url.openConnection();
    urlcon.setReadTimeout(10000);
    InputStream is = urlcon.getInputStream();
```

Or at least give you a bit more information on what the problem could be.

Comment: Yes i know but with this i don't know change inputStream() to BufferedImage

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Can't you just continue like in your example above? `BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(is)`

Comment: No because i cannot know if the address from camera is OK or not

Comment: @blackcat18: And the problem with that is what?